# Sum of recurring series ( problem in understanding steps)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't understand the steps where we multiply S by (-x), then with (-6x^2), and then add them all to get a neat sum in terms of rational functions. Were those steps obvious? How? What was the intuitive thought process behind doing them?[image]

Comment: Also, if we put x=1 in the sum S, we get S=7/6, which is completely absurd. So, what am I doing wrong here?